# How to avoid asking resource-request questions that are too localized?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, close-reasons, asking-questions

Prompted by [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89295/discussion-on-question-by-malcolm-anderson-version-of-friends-with-both-french) on [this post](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4045/85).

[resource-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request) already exceeds the bounds [other SE sites](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) set for on-topic questions. What are guidelines that can be followed to promote high-quality resource requests and discourage low-quality ones?

Comment: The post and discussion referenced in this post appear to have been deleted. It still seems like it is probably a good question, but it would be helpful if someone with access to view the deleted posts could clarify a bit more about the post question and something of the discussion for those of us who can't see it.

Comment: The question was auto-deleted by the Community user via the [`RemoveAbandonedClosed` rule](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). The question was looking for a version of a specific TV show with subs and dubs. It was originally closed as off-topic for not being about language learning. The OP disagreed with the closure, saying that although it was a shopping recommendation (request), it was still related to language learning, and should therefore be allowed, also that "the idea that there is any objectivity in language learning" is in error.

Comment: Another point OP made: "I think it's a disservice to only limit on resources that 'were designed for learning.'"